# Link não funciona no Chrome, quando aplico CSS

Tags: css, html5

tenho o seguinte código. No IE o link funciona normalmente, mas no Chrome não. Quando altero o "menu-nav" para outra coisa o link funciona.

```
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="#home-slider">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Quem Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/madeiradecormga" title="Siga-nos no Facebook" target="_blank" class="external"><span class="font-icon-social-facebook"></span></a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="shortcodes.html" class="external">Shortcodes</a></li> -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

---

```
a{
    color:#00FF00;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear 0s;   
       -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear 0s;
         -o-transition: color 0.1s linear 0s;
            transition: color 0.1s linear 0s;
}

a:hover{
    outline: 0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:active{
    outline: 0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}


a:focus{
    outline: 0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

a > img {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}

img {
    max-width: none;    
}


.
.
.
.
.


nav#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;  
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; 
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li.current a,
nav#menu #menu-nav li a:hover {
    color: #00FF00;
```

Comment: Como assim "não funciona"? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Olá, Você está usando algum JS para naveção entre as seções da nav?
coloque aqui..

Comment: BRUSHED.nav = function(){
 $('.sticky-nav').waypoint('sticky');
}

Comment: BRUSHED.goSection = function(){
 $('#nextsection').on('click', function(){
  $target = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top-30;
  
  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop : $target}, 750, 'easeOutExpo');
  return false;
 });
}

Comment: Quando clico no menu principal, para ir à seção desejada, o item muda de cor mas não chama a seção correspondente. Segue o site www.madeiradecor.com